# Hibernate can't instantiate id generator in Spring project with multiple data sources

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, db2

I have a Spring project using Hibernate with two data sources (db2 and sql-server).

As soon as I add

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SOME_SEQ")`

to a column field in my entity class, I get a `BeanCreationException` when creating the sql-server `EntityManagerFactory` because `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect` doesn't support sequences. The only place this entity is being used, though, is in a DAO that uses a db2 `EntityManagerFactory` which is using the appropriate dialect.

What am I missing?

Comment: How many Hibernate `SessionFactories` do you have in your Spring config?

Comment: I don't have any explicitly defined

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem?  I'm running into the same thing :(

Answer (score 5):

Try it with `GenerationType=AUTO` instead of `GenerationType=SEQUENCE`.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SOME_SEQ")
```

With AUTO hibernate uses the best fitting generation strategy, which is sequences for some databases and autoincrement for others.

(N. B.: I never use annotations but I use mapping files. There `<generator class="native">` works well for different database types. `GenerationType=AUTO` should be the same for annotations.)

Comment: Good suggestion -- doesn't change the behavior, though

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same issue and solved it by adding the following option to the JPA persistence-unit configuration

```
 <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

This option forces the JPA provider to only scan the listed classes instead of the whole surrounding jar, etc.

So it now looks like -

```
<persistence-unit name="MSSQLBackedPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/MSSQLServerDS</jta-data-source>

    <class>com.example.app.domain.MyEntity</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```